# How to put a new line into a wpf TextBlock control?

Tags: c#, wpf, newline, textblock

I'm fetching text from an XML file, and I'd like to insert some new lines that are interpreted by the textblock render as new lines.

I've tried:

```
<data>Foo bar baz \n baz bar</data>
```

But the data is still displayed without the new line. I set the contents of `<data>` via the `.Text` property via C#.

What do I need to put in the XML in order for it to render the new line in the GUI?

I've tried something like this manually setting the text in the XAML:

```
<TextBlock Margin="0 15 0 0" Width="600">
There &#10;
is a new line.
</TextBlock>
```

And while the encoded character doesn't appear in the GUI it also doesn't give me a new line.

Comment: have you tried wrapping the return character in "quotes" <data>Foo bar baz "\n" baz bar</data>

Comment: @DJKRAZE: Quotes do nothing, neither do r and n together. :S

Comment: @BalamBalam: It's not the same, that question is explicity about the Text attribute.

Comment: I see I totally understand why "" won't work now.. I am assuming <LineBreak> would be more like a literal / key word then. my mistake.. Great answer H.B

Comment: Dan Vogel made a up to date working solution. WPF interprets \r\n into \\r\\n.

Answer (score 217, accepted):

You can try putting a new line in the data:

```
<data>Foo bar baz 
 baz bar</data>
```

If that does not work you might need to parse the string manually.

If you need direct XAML that's easy by the way:

```xml
<TextBlock>
    Lorem <LineBreak/>
    Ipsum
</TextBlock>
```

Comment: No, this doesn't do anything as well. I've even copy pasted the contents inside the XAML of the TextBlock with enter presses as new lines and it still displays it at once.

Comment: @SergioTapia: There is a difference between having the break in some data file and XAML, the XAML parser ignores whitespace, but if you, for example, deserialize some XML using the `XmlSerializer` the breaks will be retained. In Xaml you need `<LineBreak/>`.

Comment: Put the new line directly in the data...of course!  Here I just spent a lot of time trying \n, <LineBreak/>, and tons of html codes to no avail.  I should have tried simplest approach first.

Answer (score 112):

For completeness: You can also do this:

```
 <TextBlock Text="Line1&#x0a;Line 2"/>
```

x0A is the escaped hexadecimal Line Feed. The equivalent of \n

Comment: Useful in binding in a scenario such as this:- <TextBlock >
                                            <TextBlock.Text>
                                                <MultiBinding StringFormat="{}Name:{0}&#x0a;Code:{1}">
                                                    <Binding Path="Name"/>
                                                    <Binding Path="Code" />
                                                </MultiBinding>
                                            </TextBlock.Text>
                                        </TextBlock>

Comment: I would add this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9021649/what-x0a-x0d-code-does-in-c-sharp-while-writing-csv/9021756#9021756like an explanation to the answer.

Answer (score 25):

you must use

```
 < SomeObject xml:space="preserve" > once upon a time ...
      this line will be below the first one < /SomeObject>
```

Or if you prefer :

```
 <SomeObject xml:space="preserve" />  once upon a time... &#10; this line below < / SomeObject>
```

watch out : if you both use &10 AND you go to the next line in your text, you'll have TWO empty lines.

here for details :
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms788746.aspx

Answer (score 24):

You can also use binding

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding MyText}"/>
```

And set MyText like this:

```
Public string MyText
{
    get{return string.Format("My Text \n Your Text");}
}
```

Comment: You don't even need the string.Format().  return "My Text \n Your Text"; works just fine.

Answer (score 13):

Even though this is an old question, I've just come across the problem and solved it differently from the given answers. Maybe it could be helpful to others.

I noticed that even though my XML files looked like:

```
<tag>
 <subTag>content with newline.\r\nto display</subTag>
</tag>
```

When it was read into my C# code the string had double backslashes.

```
\\r\\n
```

To fix this I wrote a ValueConverter to strip the extra backslash.

```
public class XmlStringConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(
        object value,
        Type targetType,
        object parameter,
        CultureInfo culture)
    {
        string valueAsString = value as string;
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(valueAsString))
        {
            return value;
        }

        valueAsString = valueAsString.Replace("\\r\\n", "\r\n");
        return valueAsString;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(
        object value,
        Type targetType,
        object parameter,
        CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Comment: Along with having to add `TextWrapping="Wrap"` (and `AcceptsReturn="True"` if this were a TextBox) in the XAML on the TextBlock, you had it right, and this should be the answer - but just say to do the `.Replace()` on the value coming from the database - no need for a fancy function:  `valueAsString = valueAsString.Replace("\\r\\n", "\r\n");`  Any value entered using the Return key will get written to the DB just fine - it's when C# gets a hold of it to display the value that problems are caused, as you noted.  So this would need to be called onload of the text.

Answer (score 10):

If all else fails you can also use

```
"My text needs a line break here" + System.Environment.NewLine + " This should be a new line"
```

Answer (score 9):

```
<TextBlock Margin="4" TextWrapping="Wrap" FontFamily="Verdana" FontSize="12">
        <Run TextDecorations="StrikeThrough"> Run cannot contain inline</Run>
        <Span FontSize="16"> Span can contain Run or Span or whatever 
            <LineBreak />
        <Bold FontSize="22" FontFamily="Times New Roman" >Bold can contains 
            <Italic>Italic</Italic></Bold></Span>
</TextBlock>
```

Answer (score 2):

Using System.Environment.NewLine is the only solution that worked for me.
When I tried \r\n, it just repeated the actual \r\n in the text box.

Comment: +1 This solution works for me when I use ```String.Join()``` to my list of string. Example: ```String.Join(System.Environment.NewLine, manyStrings);```

Answer (score 0):

Insert a "line break" or a "paragraph break" in a RichTextBox "rtb" like this:

```
var range = new TextRange(rtb.SelectionStart, rtb.Selection.End); 
range.Start.Paragraph.ContentStart.InsertLineBreak();
range.Start.Paragraph.ContentStart.InsertParagraphBreak();
```

The only way to get the NewLine items is by inserting text with "\r\n" items first, and then applying more code which works on Selection and/or TextRange objects. This makes sure that the \par items are converted to \line items, are saved as desired, and are still correct when reopening the *.Rtf file. That is what I found so far after hard tries. My three code lines need to be surrounded by more code (with loops) to set the TextPointer items (.Start .End .ContentStart .ContentEnd) where the Lines and Breaks should go, which I have done with success for my purposes.

Answer (score 0):

```
        StringBuilder somestext = new StringBuilder();
        somestext.AppendLine("this is some text on line 1");
        somestext.AppendLine(TB_Tag_Linebreak);
        somestext.AppendLine("this is some more text on line 2"); 
        return somestext.ToString();
```

Answer (score 0):

Define a property which replaces *\n* with *System.Environment.Newline* on set:

```
private string _data;
public string Data
{
    get => _data; 
    set {
        _data = value.Replace("\\n", System.Environment.NewLine);
        OnPropertyChanged();
    }
}
```

Bind your textbox to the property:

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding Data}" />
```

Read the xml data and assign it to the property

```
Data = ...data fetched from xml...
```

Any \n in the xml data is displayed as a new line in the TextBox.

Answer (score 0):

just from the @Ketobomb suggestion, could you use this in your style:

```
 <Style x:Key="TextBlockTestStyle" TargetType="TextBlock">       
    <Setter Property="Text" Value="line1!&#x0a;Line2&#x0a;Line3"/>
 </Setter>
```

and use it in this way:

```
 <TextBlock x:Name="TextBlockTest" Style="{StaticResource TextBlockTestStyle}"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

In case you are binding the content, this works very well:

```
<TextBlock>
   <Run Text="{Binding Text1}"/> <LineBreak/>
   <Run Text="{Binding Text2}"/> <LineBreak/>
   <Run Text="{Binding Text3}"/>
</TextBlock>
```

Answer (score -3):

You have to ensure that the textblock has this option enabled:

```
AcceptsReturn="True"
```

Comment: AcceptsReturn is only for TextBox, not TextBlock