# what "\",\x0A\x0D" code does in C# while writing CSV

Tags: c#, csv

Can anybody please tell me what its checking in following condition.

```
if (s.IndexOfAny("\",\x0A\x0D".ToCharArray()) > -1)
```

Answer (score 27, accepted):

It's checking if there is any Quotation Mark `"`, Comma `,`, a Line Feed `\x0A` or Carriage Return `\x0D` in the string `s`.

`\x0A` is the escaped hexadecimal Line Feed. The equivalent of `\n`.
`\x0D` is the escaped hexadecimal Carriage Return. The equivalent of `\r`.

Comment: thanks for your reply. I don't want to check the comma, so if I remove the comma from the code, will it still work?

Comment: If you remove the comma then it will check for Quotation Mark, Line Feed and Carriage Return.

Comment: Why wouldn't the author use \r\n? I just recently viewed an example for an SQL CLR WriteToFile sp and it used \r\n for writing lines but for searching for what characters to escape it used "\",\x0A\x0D" - couldn't it be just "\",\r\n"?

Comment: @JayCroghan ask that as a separate question and I'll answer it ;)  . The reason is because C is not defined in terms of ASCII, only in terms of an 'execution character set'. It's entirely possible for `\n` to translate to `\x0A\0D` or even `\x1\x2\x3`.

Comment: @Pod That was 4 years ago mate hah!

Comment: @JayCroghan did it sort the issue though?

Answer (score 3):

`\x0A\x0D` are escaped hexadecimal line feed and carriage return characters.